# Mysql add a row to table, based on ID and field from other table

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table called item_texts

```
id|rec_id|text
-----------------
1 |21    |point(123
2 |21    |nothing
3 |91    |empty
4 |2     |point(123
5 |500   |point(123
```

and a table called tags

```
id|tag_id|rec_id
----------------------
1 |1     |34
2 |2     |34
3 |34    |21
4 |1     |2867
```

These are both essentially lookup tables, the first assigns texts to a record, and the second assigns tags to a record.

Essentially for each item that has text like POINT I want add a record to the tags database with that items record id and the tag id 45..

So it goes through the item_texts table, looking for an item with point as text, using the example above rec_id 21, 2, 500. Then insert the tag with an id of 45 into the tags table with the record id it got from the texts table. So I end up with a tags table that looks like this.

```
id|tag_id|rec_id
----------------------
1 |1     |34
2 |2     |34
3 |34    |21
4 |1     |2867
5 |45    |21
6 |45    |2
7 |45    |500
```

I can select the items in the table

```
  SELECT * FROM `item_texts` WHERE `text` LIKE 'POINT%'
```

and I can do the insert query, 
      INSERT INTO tags VALUES ('', 45, 21)
im just not sure how to tie them together so the 21 in the insert is sourced from each item that matches in the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do it.

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag_id,rec_id)
SELECT 45, rec_id FROM `item_texts` WHERE `text` LIKE 'POINT%'
```

Comment: hmm that hasnt worked, It threw an error with my syntax. But I cant work out why its selecting 45 in your query when I want to insert that. I have made my original question clearer (i hope!!)

Comment: Actually it is working now. I removed the Values and it seems to have done the trick. So INSERT INTO tags (tag_id,rec_id). Edit your answer and i will award :-D